# Having an issue when running freshly built exe file with Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a fresh project in Unity3d and I've tried to build and run it.

However, after short loading (window with white background), I am getting an error: Oops!...

This is the part of my output_log:

```
The resource Internal-ErrorShader.shader could not be loaded from the resource file!

(Filename:  Line: 1020)

The resource Sprites-Default.mat could not be loaded from the resource file!

(Filename:  Line: 1020)

Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
- Completed reload, in  0.050 seconds
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\FreshProjectTest\build\test_Data\Managed\System.dll (this message is harmless)
desktop: 1920x1080 60Hz; virtual: 1920x1080 at 0,0
<RI> Initializing input.

XInput1_3.dll not found. Trying XInput9_1_0.dll instead...
<RI> Input initialized.

<RI> Initialized touch support.

The resource UnitySplash-text.png could not be loaded from the resource file!

(Filename:  Line: 1020)
```

Comment: Sounds like some update messed up or something. A clean re-install of unity should fix this, I think, but maybe someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem indicated in the log is that the Unity splash, internal shader resource files and some material is not loaded. Try re-installing unity entirely from scratch and see what happens.

Comment: I am gonna do that but I don't like that much as a solution. Anyway thanks a lot for an effort. Will let you know when I'm done.